# Save/Restore(Get/Set) absolute position of UI control (textbox) dynamically with C# code in Win8 Metro Store app

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-8, microsoft-metro, dynamically-generated

as said in title, it's about Windows 8 Metro style store app.

-Textbox is dynamically generated by Code
 - Textbox can be dragged by user to anywhere to the screen
 - user can save the location of textbox anytime
 - user can restore the location of its previously saved location on screen.
 - List item

eg.

```
TextBox t = new TextBox();
t.Name = "TextBoxControl";
// add event for dragging
t.ManipulationDelta += t_ManipulationDelta;
t.RenderTransform = dragTranslation;
// Add textbox to screen
Basic_Root.Children.Add(t)
```

User can drag and textbox anywhere in the screen, but i need to save the position of this dragged textbox's new location. And there is a button, once clicked, will restore the textbox to its previously saved location, may I know how this can be done?

I thought of saving the Margin value of textbox, and set it later for restoring its position, but it didn't work.

I found something about....

```
var ttv = MainTextBlock.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
Point screenCoords = ttv.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0)
```

This allow me to see the x,y location of the dragged textbox, so I save the Point, but how can I restore textbox's location with this saved Point?

Many Thanks!

Comment: You should use `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties rather than margin.